# Framework for CMS development

Tags: web-development, framework

I have a question regarding a big project of mine. Me and my business ***intend to develop a web application*** for business purposes. We are currently evaluating which framework / CMS we should be using to achieve the best result.

**What our web application should feature:**

We want to work on a website that serves as a communication platform for partners and users. In order to register, a monthly fee (subscription) is required. Each company has its own login. Each company can have employees with individual logins, so we need a system managing access permissions.

Moreover, we intend to implement a detailed search functionality, so that users can search each other based on desired criteria. A random example: User X wants to find all users who love fish, ice hockey, castles and cars. Furthermore, user X wants to find all users in a certain region and the area around it (X kilometers around it). Personally, I would love to have a google maps add in with a dynamic circle visualizing the region user X is searching in.

Additionally, users should have an option to create detailed profiles including images. Moreover, users should be able to interact with each other using a chat (similar to facebook, just as a reference). We also want to have a newsfeed (similar to Xing / LinkedIn / Facebook), in which users can "subscribe" to each other to stay up-to-date. Again, the way Facebook's feed works in probably the best example right here.

For future prospects, we have thought about adding a chat-bot incooperating google calendar, so that two users can make a phone-call appointment with the help of a chat bot comparing the two users' time schedules and automatically suggesting an appointment  to both users.

**My question to the community:**

We are uncertain which framework or content-management-system we should be using to create this web application. As for right now, we have a bit of experience with Laravel including HTML, CSS, PHP and SQL databases. In a past project, we made use of XAMPP to get everything running.

Should we use Laravel again due to the fact that we've got some experience with it already? Are other frameworks like Wordpress, Angular JS or other frameworks we are yet not aware of possibly better for our venture? In a nutshell, we want to accomplish our goals as fast as possible, as beautiful as possible and as easy to manage as possible. Nontheless, we don't want to limit ourselves if we want to expand our application in the years to come.

Some issues we were having with Laravel last time around included the lack of proper front-end development. An editor to create a website making it responsive automatically would be quite beneficial. Futhermore, the implementation of a MySQL database was more complex than we wanted it to be, so if there's a framework simplifying this process, let me know :) If you are aware of a way to combine let's say Laravel with a "website-designer-tool", let us know as well please.

**I'm thankful for any responses, suggestions and recommendations**

Comment: Ok, I start to understand how this works now :) Thanks

Comment: Cool! Then I can cleanup comments now. Good hunting!